# How to check the longest substrings in python

Tags: python

I have a text and a list of concepts as follows.

```
concepts = ["data mining", "data", "data source"]
text = "levels and data mining of dna data source methylation"
```

I want to identify if the `concepts` in the list are in the `text` and replace all the occurrences of `concepts[1:]` with `concepts[0]`. Therefore, the results of the above text should be;

```
"levels and data mining of dna data mining methylation"
```

My code looks as follows:

```
concepts = ["data mining", "data", "data source"]
text = "levels and data mining of dna data source methylation"

if any(word in text for word in concepts):
    for terms in concepts[1:]:
        if terms in text:
            text=text.replace(terms,concepts[0])
        text=' '.join(text.split())
    print(text)
```

However, I get the output as;

```
levels and data mining mining of dna data mining source methylation
```

It looks like the concept `data` is replaced with `data mining` which is incorrect. More specifically, I want the longest options to consider first when replacing.

It did not work even when I change the order of `concepts`.

```
concepts = ["data mining", "data source", "data"]
text = "levels and data mining of dna data source methylation"

if any(word in text for word in concepts):
    for terms in concepts[1:]:
        if terms in text:
            text=text.replace(terms,concepts[0])
        text=' '.join(text.split())
    print(text)
```

I got the following output for the above code.

```
levels and data mining mining of dna data mining mining methylation
```

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: @roganjosh Thanks for the comment. However, I get a syntax error for the line you have mentioned.

Comment: You are right :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is your iterated strategy that does the replacements one term at a time. Because your replacement term contains one of the terms you're replacing, you wind up doing replacements on things you already changed to your replacement term in prior iterations.

One way to get around this would be to do all of these replacements *atomically* so that they all happen simultaneously, and the output never affects the results of other replacements. There are a couple of strategies for this:

1. You could break the string into tokens that match your various terms, and replace them after the fact (and ensure that there aren't any overlaps).
2. You could use a function that does atomic replacement of multiple options.

An example of #2 is the `sub()` method of Python's `re` library. Here's an example of its use:

```
import re

concepts = ["data mining", "data source", "data"]
text = "levels and data mining of dna data source methylation"

# Sort targets by descending length, so longer targets that
# might contain shorter ones are found first
targets = sorted(concepts[1:], key=lambda x: len(x), reverse=True)
# Use re.escape to generate version of the targets with special characters escaped
target_re = "|".join(re.escape(item) for item in targets)

result = re.sub(target_re, concepts[0], text)
```

Note that this will still result in `data mining mining` with your original set of replacements, because it has no concept of the existing `mining` that comes after `data`. If you want to avoid this, you could simply include the actual item you're replacing with as a replacement target as well, so that it gets matched before the shorter term:

```
import re

concepts = ["data mining", "data source", "data"]
text = "levels and data mining of dna data source methylation"

# Sort targets by descending length, so longer targets that
# might contain shorter ones are found first
#
# !!!No [1:] !!!
#
targets = sorted(concepts, key=lambda x: len(x), reverse=True)
# Use re.escape to generate version of the targets with special characters escaped
target_re = "|".join(re.escape(item) for item in targets)

result = re.sub(target_re, concepts[0], text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Amber's Solution is very clean.  I wrote out a long form version with some comments walking through the words and looking ahead to check for matches.  It should help you with the concepts your original code was missing (checking for multi-word matches and avoiding double replacements)
This would not work as-is for every list of "concepts" as it only handles replacements of the same number of words or a single word match.

```
concepts = ["data mining", "data source", "data"]
text = "levels and data mining of dna data source methylation"
textSplit = text.split()
finalText = ""
maxX = len(textSplit)
#add a look ahead for mulitwords
for x in range(0, maxX):
    tempSplit = concepts[0].split()
    tempMax = len(tempSplit)
    foundFullMatch = True
    for y in range(0,tempMax):
        if (x + tempMax <= maxX):
            if (textSplit[x+y] != tempSplit[y]):
                foundFullMatch = False
        else:
            foundFullMatch = False
    if (foundFullMatch):
        #skip past it in the loop
        x = x + tempMax
        continue
    else:
        # now start looking at rest of list - make sure is sorted with most words first
        for terms in concepts[1:]:
            tempSplit2 = terms.split()
            tempMax2 = len(tempSplit2)
            foundFullMatch = True
            for y in range(0,tempMax2):
                if (x + tempMax2 <= maxX):
                    if (textSplit[x+y] != tempSplit2[y]):
                        foundFullMatch = False
                else:
                    foundFullMatch = False
            if (foundFullMatch):
                if (tempMax == tempMax2):
                    # found match same number words - replace
                    for y in range(0,tempMax2):
                        textSplit[x+y] = tempSplit[y]
                    x = x + tempMax
                    continue
                else:
                    # found match but not same number of words as concept 0
                    if (tempMax2 == 1):
                        #covers 1 word answer
                        textSplit[x] = concepts[0]
                        continue
print(" ".join(textSplit))
```